# Can I use fight in place of fighting?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, learning

In the context below:

"Months of American diplomacy have failed to stop the fighting in northern Ethiopia.
Now, the civil war is plunging into its most alarming phase yet."

is "fight in northern Ethiopia" interchangeable by "fighting in northern Ethiopia"????

if I could extend this post I would ask also if "interchangeable by" is correct in the question

Answer (score 2):

No, "fight" is not interchangeable *with* "fighting".

The verb "fight" (as in "fighting") refers generally to any situation where people are in an aggressive conflict, usually against someone else, but not always. It includes war.

The noun "fight" (as in "the fight"), on the other hand, refers only to a few very specific types of conflict, usually fisticuffs or a verbal conflict. It does not include military conflict.

Answer (score 1):

"fight" has a higher level meaning than "fighting", putting more importance on the underlying purpose of the conflict:

- The **fight** for equal rights.
- The **fight** against malaria.
- The **fight** over Crimea has been going on for centuries.

"fighting", as a noun (gerund), is more about the ongoing process, putting more importance for what is actually happening:

- Jones continued **fighting** for justice in the Senate today.
- **Fighting** in eastern Ukraine intensified today as … .
- Bishops in Ethiopia “deeply saddened” by resumption of **fighting** in Tigray.

Or:

- **Fighting** was suspended today, a day considered holy by both sides in the **fight**.

Answer (score 0):

In the example given you may interchangeably use "the fight" and "the fighting" and many English speakers will understand. You may say "interchangeable by" and be understood but many English speakers may prefer "interchangeable with".